# cakePHP - JSON_encode ajax response- Undefined

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp

I have the following code

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$data['success'] = true;
$data['data'] = 'Target Successfully set';
echo json_encode($data);
```

which sends a response to an ajax request..

The I have the following

```
success:function (response, textStatus) {
        if (response.error){
           //show error message...
        }else{
           //show success message...
           console.log(response); // shows what is expected 
           //ie. {"success":true,"data":"Target Successfully set"} 
        }
```

However when I try to access response.data, I am getting `Undefined`... What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax call, or set the corresponding header in CakePHP.

Comment: That's not the [normal way to generate json responses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not telling javascript what kind of data you're returning, so it's considered plain text and so what you see on your log is the just a full string containing what's was outputed by the server.

`response.error` is also undefined, but since `undefined == false` in javascript, you didn't see it.

You have to either set `dataType: "json"` in your ajax call, or add `$this->response->type('application/json');` in your CakePHP action.